# How can I use a class method to create a custom class instance?

Tags: python, class, instance, static-methods, class-method

I'm quite new to Python OOP and trying to create a class I can generate instances of in these two ways according to whether I want to customize the instance or not:

```
alien_one = Alien(1)
alien_two = Alien(1).customize(anger=5, emotion=1)
```

I got the following code working after messing around with classmethods and staticmethods, which I feel I should have been using according to other threads:

```
class Alien(object):
    def __init__(self, polarity):
        self.polarity = {1 : 'friendly', 2 : 'aggressive'}

    def customize(self, **kwargs):
        for event in kwargs:
            # // process events to change self.polarity
        return self
```

Is this code appropriate for creating an instance of Alien or should I be using method decorators to generate the instance? There is just something that feels broken about this before I've started.

Edit: Thanks all for the responses, the general consensus is to pass any expressions or kwargs into `__init__`. Some of the example code I have been referring to looked like this:

```
query = Tweet.update(is_published=True).where(Tweet.creation_date < today)
```

which is an example taken from the Peewee ORM. When I have tried to use method decorators (static/class) inside my class I have lost the `is_published` parameter and have no access to it. For understanding more clearly can anybody explain how both `is_published` and `Tweet.creation_date` is likely to be received inside the class object, it does seem that query is a brand new instance of the Tweet class. I'm only using Peewee as an example to understand how this code works rather than trying to figure how any details of Peewee works itself.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just pass the `**kwargs` to `__init__`?

Comment: @katy lavallee, I have seen similar syntax used on python ORM's for the get/where methods and it was easier to read when there were a lot of arguments going into the 'where' method. My Alien class is just an example and I wanted to get the process working :)

Comment: @Mozzie Can you specify your use case? `__init__` is definitely the way to go here, and I suspect it's also the way to go in your more complicated set-up. I wouldn't learn the basics of Python OOP by trying to copy an ORM's syntax

Comment: This feels like a primarily opinion based question -- with that said, my opinion aligns with brianpck and I suspect you should be passing the **kwargs into the constructor. It's perfectly fine for the constructor to call the customize method and pass it the **kwargs for further processing if you don't want your __init__ to get too messy

Comment: @brianpck Okidoke, I'll go the `__init__` way, but can anybody provide an explanation as to how the ORM syntax works as it seems a fairly popular way of doing things... just for my own learning. For example: `query = Tweet.update(is_published=True).where(Tweet.creation_date < today)` in Peewee ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're doing this to mutate your instances after creation. If this is the case, consider restructuring your code for immutability as there are [very real advantages in many situations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151733/if-immutable-objects-are-good-why-do-people-keep-creating-mutable-objects). If you're not mutating, take @katy lavallee's advice and move this into __init__.

You can use the setattr built to programmatically set fields on an instance:

```
for key, val in kwargs.items():
    setattr(self, key, val)
```

If this is python 2 (if so, make the switch) you'll want to replace the call to items() with iteritems().

Comment: Why switch to .iteritems() for 2.x?

Comment: In Python 3, items() returns an iterator, while in Python 2, items() returns a prebuilt list and iteritems() returns an iterator. A full discussion of why you should prefer to use iterators over prebuilt is beyond the scope of comments but two big reasons are memory efficiency and the ability to avoid unneeded computation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing is to define which attributes should be internal, and which attributes should be exposed to the interface. For example, you may want the polarity to be an internal attribute, dependent on the anger.

```
class Alien(object):

    polarity = 1
    polarity_names = {1 : 'friendly', 2 : 'aggressive'}

    def __init__(self, anger=1):
        self.customize(
            anger = anger,
        )

    def get_polarity(self):
        return self.polarity_names[self.polarity]

    def customize(self, **kwargs):
        for feeling_name, feeling_intensity in kwargs.items():
            if feeling_name == 'anger':
                self.polarity = feeling_intensity


alien_one = Alien()
print('Alien 1 polarity: ' + alien_one.get_polarity())

alien_two = Alien(anger=2)
print('Alien 2 polarity: ' + alien_two.get_polarity())
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, is this confirming that `return self` is okay to use for creating an instance of `Alien` as you have done with `alien_two`?